# Bluetooth Phone Audio with phone mic still active

Tags: bluetooth-audio

I need to bluetooth the audio output from a Galaxy SIII in phone mode to a cochlear implant processor using a bluetooth adapter plugged into the processor with 3.5mm jack.  But still need to use the mic on the phone for the audio input on a call.  I am willing to get a new phone to obtain this functionality to split the audio in/out.  I purchased an HTC Bluetooth Stereo clip.  It works for streaming media on the phone to the implant, but the phone mode audio will not stream to the adapter.